# Trying to get random array value to echo on element class

Tags: php, arrays

Like the question says I am working with the `array_rand` function in php and my goal is to get this function to randomly generate a class in my loop.  Currently it just prints the 2nd value in the array each time.  How can I have this echo a random class for the div in my loop?

```
if ($featured_query->have_posts()) :   

                    while ($featured_query->have_posts()) :  

                        $featured_query->the_post(); 
                        $masonry_classes = array(
                        'grid-item',
                        'grid-item--width2'
                        );
                    $random_class = array_rand($masonry_classes, 2);
                         ?>
                    <li <?php //post_class( $classes ); ?> class="<?php echo $masonry_classes[$random_class[1]]; ?>">
```

Comment: why are you picking 2 from the array and using only 1 ?

Comment: Its a loop running and I want a class to be randomly assigned to the loop to use the isotope masonry grid, there are only two classes I need to randomly choose from

Comment: `echo $masonry_classes[array_rand($masonry_classes)];` should work just fine

Comment: Geez, I swear I tried that based on the PHP.net explanation.  That did the trick, post as answer and I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you only want one array element you can combine the (random)selection and display on to a convenient one-liner:

```
echo $masonry_classes[array_rand($masonry_classes)];
```

ref: [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you misunderstood how `array_rand` works.

If you don't specify the second parameter or set it to `1`, the function will return an integer which is an index of the random entry in the array.

If you set the second parameter to a number greater than `1` then the function will return an array of randomly picked indexes.

So, if you do:

```php
$rand = array_rand($masonry_classes);
```

...you will end up with with either `0` or `1` (because your array contains two entries whose indexes are `0` and `1` respectively). In that case you can do

```php
$class = $masonry_classes[array_rand($masonry_classes)];
```

to retrieve one random class and the following to print it:

```php
class="<?php print $class; ?>"
```

If you do

```php
$rand = array_rand($masonry_classes, 2);
```

then it will return 2 random indexes which in your case are both, `0` and `1`.

To retrieve the matching entries you'll now have to do the following:

```php
$classes = array_intersect_key($masonry_classes, array_flip($rand));
```

To render them in your HTML simply do the following join:

```php
class="<?php print join(' ', $classes); ?>"
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get what the downvote is for. I thought I clearly explained to the author what he/she was doing wrong.

Comment: I thought this was a pretty thorough answer and helped clear up my confusion.  Dagon answered first and referenced the link but thank for your answer because it helped :)