# Assign random class in php but limit the number of time a class can be attributed

Tags: php, class, random

Following a post on stackoverflow I was able to modify my code to assign a random class to my div's. The problem I am now facing is that since it's random, it's partially working with materializecss.

Basically when I have 5 or 6 posts to display I wanted to randomize the look and have various column sizing. There are only two options (either it's a 6 columns width, or a 3 column with). Each "row" should be 12 columns in total.

Here's my question: how can I limit the number of time the "col s12 m6 l6" class is given?

Here's the code :

```
if($count == 5):
    $the_class = array(
        'col s12 m6 l3',
        'col s12 m6 l6'
    );
    $class = $the_class[array_rand($the_class)];

endif;
```

And then I echo the class :

```
<?php echo $class; ?>
```

When the random assignment is giving 3 times the "col s12 m6 l6" it's perfect but when it's more or less than it's not working.
I understand that array_rand might not be the best way to accomplish this but it was by far the easiest method for me.

I was gonna use the same code with modifications for when I have 6 items to display. I believe that having either 2 or 4 times the "col s12 m6 l6" should do the trick for the second part.

Here is the full code to include the part where I handle the other situations (when I have less than 4 posts to display) :

```
<?php
    $my_query = new WP_Query($query_args);
    $count = $my_query->post_count;
    $i = 1;
    query_posts( $query_args );
    while (have_posts()) :
    the_post();
        // For 1-4 create a single row
        if($count == 1)$class = "col s12";
        if($count == 2)$class = "col s12 m6 l6";
        if($count == 3)$class = "col s12 m4 l4";
        if($count == 4)$class = "col s12 m6 l3";

        //For 5 videos
        if($count == 5) {
            $the_class = array(
                'col s12 m6 l3',
                'col s12 m6 l6'
            );
        $class = $the_class[array_rand($the_class)];
        }
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="<?php echo $class; ?> featured-videos-item">
        <?php  if (has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
        <div class="featured-videos-item-content featured-videos-low" style="background: url('<?php echo get_thumbnail_url($post->ID); ?>') 50% 50% no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
        <?php  endif; ?>

            <div class="featured-videos-item-content--table">
                <div class="featured-videos-item-content--cell">
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                    <a class="featured-videos-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
                        <h3 class="featured-videos-title with-post--meta"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
<?php
    $i++;
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
</div>
```

EDIT : I've removed the nested if.

EDIT 2 : Here's the link to the post where I found this solution [Trying to get random array value to echo on element class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32386183/trying-to-get-random-array-value-to-echo-on-element-class)

EDIT 3 : The `$rand = array_rand($the_class);` did seem unecessary and the code is working without it, although I still have no clue how to track down or limit the number of time the "col s12 m4 l6" is being used.

Comment: Something in your code is wrong... very wrong. maybe link to the previous question you are referencing to? by the way, the nested if is unnecessary; because if it is in the first if, the `$count` is already five.

Comment: You would have to track how many times the column width has been used previously and if it is over some threshold (2 or 4 depending on size) then not pick that value again (or remove it from the available choices).

Comment: What is the point of `$rand = array_rand($the_class);` when you aren't using `$rand`? Are you using it somewhere else?

Comment: You say 12 columns but then you say _3 times the "col s12 m6 l6" it's perfect_ but 3 x 6 = 18???

Comment: Please explain on how many rows you spread the 5 or 6 posts (two?), and provide the code where you attribute the classes to the divs. What happens with 4 posts or 7 posts?

Comment: When I have less than 4 posts it's being displayed on a single row like this : `if($count == 1)$class = "col s12";
if($count == 2)$class = "col s12 m6 l6";
if($count == 3)$class = "col s12 m4 l4";
if($count == 4)$class = "col s12 m6 l3";` Now I was trying to work out the 5 posts, and then 6. I do know that 3 x6 is 18, but since i'm using masonry I was hoping that it would be able to handle this and have it so : 3 post with l6 and 2 posts with l3 (which is 24 hence : two rows of 12)

Comment: Can't you show the code where you loop through your div-generation? I don't see any code where you assign two different classes in one count case (e.g. 5). All the code you provide ends up with one value for `$class` given the `$count`...

Comment: Added full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please use curly braces; it makes code 86 times more readable and maintainable
2. I think this should work:

---

```
if($count >= 5){

    $l = array(3, 6);
    $total_cols = 0;

    echo '<div class="row">';
    foreach($posts as $post){
        if($total_cols < 9){
            $chosen_l = array_rand($l);
        }
        else{
            $chosen_l = 3;
        }

        echo '<div class="col s12 m6 l'.$chosen_l.'"></div>';

        $total_cols += $chosen_l;

        if($total_cols === 12){
            $total_cols = 0;
            echo '</div><div class="row">';
        }
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: This options seems a good one but I can't get it to work with my code since i'm not using foreach and it's not working with the rest of the code (when I have 4 posts or less since they are displayed by $class) i've added the full code on my original post.

Comment: @SwayRaines I see you've accepted my answer. Were you able to get your code working? My answer was only meant to serve as a logical adaptation because I realize that your actual code is probably different than what I show.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code (if I have understood your question properly) to achieve a full 12 part of col space. See [this](https://3v4l.org/iagYA):

```
<?php
!defined('MAX_LIFE')?define('MAX_LIFE',3):null;
$classes = array(
    array('life' => MAX_LIFE%4 == 0 ? MAX_LIFE : (MAX_LIFE%4 == 1 ? MAX_LIFE+3 : (MAX_LIFE%4 == 2 ? MAX_LIFE+2 : MAX_LIFE+1)), 'class' => 'col s12 m6 l3', 'space' => 3),
    array('life' => MAX_LIFE%2 ? MAX_LIFE+1 : MAX_LIFE, 'class' => 'col s12 m6 l6', 'space' => 6),
);
$memory = 0;
do
{
    if ($classes[0]['life'] > 0 && $classes[1]['life'] > 0)
        $idx = rand(0,1);
    else if ($classes[0]['life'] > 0)
        $idx = 0;
    else if ($classes[1]['life'] > 0)
        $idx = 1;
    else
        break;
    if ($memory + $classes[$idx]['space'] > 12)
        continue;
    else if ($memory + $classes[$idx]['space'] == 12)
        $memory = 0;
    else
        $memory += $classes[$idx]['space'];
    $classes[$idx]['life']--;
    echo $classes[$idx]['class'] . "\n";
} while(1);
```

As you can see, the life has to match so that col space fills all 12 (eg `l3` has multiples of 4 lifes, yet `l6` has multiples of 2 lifes.